# Check each commit before it's commited on svn

Tags: svn, commit

I have a quite big project and i want to give some of the work to an indian company.

The project is hosted on a SVN Server, I want that one of my employees checks each commit of the extern developers and valid ( or not ) the changes ( valid = push the commit to our svn repository ).
I want that the extern developers can always do Update to get the most updated version.

Do you know how can i achieve this ?

I taught, for my employee, to have an svn folder where Update comes from a url ( svn for externs ) , and commit goes to another url ( our svn ).

And for the externs, a folder which does Update from our svn server, and commit to their svn.

Well it seems complicated ( maybe impossible ), has someone did this already?

Answer (score 1):

A native way to it is with two branches. Let name it `branch_development` and `branch_final`. All development goes to `branch_development` and the reviewed commits will be merged to `branch_final` (use tortoiseSVN or something like this). But be aware if you omit/revise to many commits it will lead you to merge conflicts (technical and logical).

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem that the developers should have an updated version ( some of the commits can go directly to Branch_final, when my own employees are working, so i'll have to merge from branch_final to branch_development too.... )

Comment: Than you my consider MS Team Foundation Server, never worked with but I have heard that you can do something like review-task with it.

Comment: thanks for the glue, i'll see what fonctionalities it has, i hope it's compatible with svn servers, i keep waiting for an answer for other developement tools, not all our projects uses microsoft techs